# WCF Error: Soap Headers are not supported by the None Message Version

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap

I am trying to add Streaming for File Transfers in WCF. 
My WCF Service has 2 Endpoints - BasicHttpBinding and WebHttpBinding.

I am getting an error - Soap Headers are not supported by the None Message Version on the Method that is doing the File Transfers. 
As soon as I comment my WebHttpBinding endpoint in web.config and only have my BasicHttpBinding, the error disappears.

I have searched for lots of posts on this but unable to find the reason and any solution to this problem.

**If i comment the Upload Method, it works fine and there are no errors.**

here is my config

```
<endpoint address="basic" 
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="myBasicBinding" 
          contract="IService" /> 
<endpoint address="web" 
          binding="webHttpBinding" 
          behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior"
          bindingConfiguration="webbinding" 
          contract="IService" /> 
<endpoint address="mex" 
          binding="mexHttpBinding" 
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

---

```
<binding name="myBasicBinding" 
         maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
         closeTimeout="01:50:00" 
         openTimeout="01:50:00" 
         sendTimeout="01:50:00" 
         receiveTimeout="01:50:00" 
         transferMode="Streamed" 
         messageEncoding="Mtom" >
<binding name="webbinding" transferMode="StreamedRequest">
```

This is the service

```
 <service name="EmployeeAPI.Service" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
```

Method:

```
    [OperationBehavior]
    public void UploadFile_WorksFineForlocalDrive(FileUploadMessage request)
    { ... }

[MessageContract]
    public class FileUploadMessage
    {
        [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
        public FileMetaData Metadata;
        [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
        public Stream FileByteStream;
    }
```

Comment: please post your config, you might have to use a customerbinding and use a lesser version of SOAP

Comment: i dont see your bindings nvermind

Comment: what about the service side?

Comment: check your <service name="here"  this might be the incorrect name

Comment: This service is already working and is in use.Do you think this could be a problem?

Comment: Are you using SOAP headers anywhere? What if you use a different `transferMode` on the `webBinding`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode.aspx may help.

Comment: Also, exactly where do you get the exception? And, BTW, it's not an "error", it's an exception.

Comment: I am getting an exception while trying to update the service reference from my Unit Testing project that is inside same solution. I also noticed that my-test project-app.config was missing the webhttp endpoint. I added it manually but didnt help.

Comment: My http-endpoint is using transferMode="Streamed" and messageEncoding="Mtom". My  webhttp-endpoint is using messageEncoding="Mtom". Please see above. I also added my method signature in my post above.

Comment: If i comment Upload Method, it works fine and there are no errors.

Comment: Please let me know if you want me to provide any other details.

Answer (score 2):

As I know, webHttpBinding uses MessageVersion.None and None is the message version that does not use SOAP or WS-Addressing, MessageVersion.None provides support for using "plain old XML" (POX)-style messaging.
In this style you do not deal with SOAP Envelope and SOAP headers ..
And, Because you have used MessageHeader in your message contract, If you don't comment WebHttpBinding endpoint in web.config you will get the error message ..